# Music theory behind songs: looking for materials

Tags: theory, learning, self-learning

I want to apologise for a potentially stupid question, but as a self-taught player I sometimes find myself in situations when I can't find a proper material.

What are the best books/websites that explain theory behind songs, i.e. not only teach which finger to put on which bar or what key to press? I have some knowledge in music theory, but I don't know how much of it I still don't know. So I want to reed some materials explaining different songs and genres to see how musicians actually apply theory to practice and how different aspects make music "distinguishable" (why Spanish music is different from Beatles songs?)

Comment: Questions asking for off-site resources such as books are generally considered off-topic here.

Comment: You wrote both "I have some knowledge in music theory" and "looking for material..." If you explain _why_ your current theory knowledge does not help to understand a song, or specific part of a song, that will make a better question, a question that probably won't be closed as "off topic."

Comment: Thank you very much for you comment. I've tried to edit my question and hope the question is a little bit better.

Comment: Somewhat relevant meta: https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/would-there-be-any-enthusiasm-for-a-single-general-theory-resources-thread

Comment: If you’re asking for recommendations, your question is off topic, no matter how you word it.

Comment: Your question is off-topic, because you are asking for resource recommendations. You could read some musical theory for beginners and listen to some well-known compositions while reading through the notes for them or - even better - try playing them yourself. And genre difference doesn't come from notes alone, it comes from effects, mastering and an assortment of other things. Listen [what black metal sounds like with a surf rock setup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NRHR5adkTtY) :)